# determining whether the composite pattern is used properly or not

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, composite

I am trying to use the composite design pattern in Java. However, I am not sure if I have used it validly/correctly. Is the code below a valid/correct use of the composite design pattern? I have a class leafGoal, which class compositeGoal extends. However, there is no interface they are implementing, which is a common pattern I saw online with the composite pattern. Does this matter? That I have no common interface for the two classes? Is it still a valid composite pattern?

```
public class leafGoal {

    String goalName;
    //private GoalStrategy strategy;
    GoalStrategy strategy;
    private Dungeon dungeon;
    private Inventory inventory;
```

```
public class compositeGoal extends leafGoal {

    ArrayList<leafGoal> goals = new ArrayList<leafGoal>();
    
    public compositeGoal(String goalName, GoalStrategy strategy, Dungeon dungeon, Inventory inventory) {
        super(goalName, strategy, dungeon, inventory);
    }

    public void addGoal(leafGoal g) {

        goals.add(g);
    }
```

Comment: A Composite is not a Leaf, so should not extend it; and a Composite can contain other Composites, not just Leafs.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, since you do not really provide any code.

You do not need an interface for a Composite. A Composite is simply a class that combines multiple objects of a certain type while being of the same type. Example: You have Items in your inventory and they all behave like Items. Some Items are Bags that can contain other Items, while being Items themselves. The Bags are Composites in this case. They contain Items and are Items themselves.

Comment: well, a compositeGoal contains an array called goals, which contains leafGoals

Answer (score 0):

you'd need at least a base/abstract class for the Component and an interface for the Composite.
The idea is to first define a common abstraction that includes all the basic operations. Then you can define another interface that defines the behaviour of the Composite.
Something like this:

```
public abstract class Node{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class Leaf : Node{
    public override void DoSomething(){
        // I am a leaf!
    }
}

public interface IComposite{
    void AddNode(Node node);
}

public class InnerNode : Node, IComposite{
    public override void DoSomething(){
        // I am NOT a leaf!
        
        // loop over the child collection and call DoSomething()
    }
    
    public void AddNode(Node node){
        // add to some inner collection
    }
}
```

note that in the `InnerNode.DoSomething()` implementation you can use pre-order, in-order or post-order traversal, it really depends on your system (or can be configurable).